# Periodic cursor in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Question

I know multiple cursor is a thing in VSCode, but is there a single action (keyboard shortcut or a command) to place a new cursor every N lines in the whole file, based on initial cursor location?

Or as an alternative good-enough solution, is there a way to generate X new cursors N lines after the current one?

#### Context

The use case behind this question is as follow:

Imagine you have a very large json file with repeating blocks in it, the content of each blocks has the same number of lines but a very high text variability on each line.

I would like to be able to multi select all blocks using the way above, and batch-copy them to another file with a similar structure this way.

#### Example

```json
{
  "main_block": {
    "name": "TEST NAME",
    "version": "1.0"
    "data_list": [
      {
        "label": "Item Name 1",
        "obj_id": "ID1111111",
        "obj_type": "TypeA",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "param1",
            "size": 0,
            "value": "test_value1"
          },
          {
            "name": "param2",
            "size": 10,
            "value": "test_value2"
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
      {
        "label": "Item Name 9",
        "obj_id": "ID9999999",
        "obj_type": "TypeB",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "param42",
            "size": 42,
            "value": "test_value42"
          },
          {
            "name": "param57",
            "size": 0,
            "value": "test_value57"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Reformulating context with the example above:

- The number of lines of each object inside `data_list` is guaranteed to be the same (17 lines).
- In order to be able to select the first object inside each `properties` array through the whole file, I am looking for a way to place a cursor every 17th lines.

Comment: you say "high text variability", but is there anything in there that _does_ repeat predictably? (based on your answer post, I assume yes, but you don't get a free pass on being clear in your question post just because you self-answer)

Comment: you can use the extension I wrote: [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number) and use the command **Place cursor based on line number, uses boolean expression**

Comment: It would be very helpful to see an example of the text that you are using.

Comment: Added a use case example for clarity.

@rioV8 The extension you wrote seems to provide pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping for it to be a native VSCode behavior, but an extension does the job just as fine, feel free to add it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want the regex to select that `properties[0]` object if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension I made: [Select By] and use the command:
**Place cursor based on line number, uses boolean expression**

For your use case the expression would be: `c+17k`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to cover the use case described above in a different way that does not involve specifying the number of line.

As this is not answering the initial question please feel free to share more relevant solutions.

For reference in case it fits your needs, here is what I did:

- Find a text that appears exactly once before or after the block you want to select.
- Select this text.
- Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`L` to select all occurenced of this text in the file and put a cursor at the end of each.
- Use `Arrow` keys to move all cursors at the beginning of the target block.
- Use `Shift`+`DownArrow` to select the whole block and do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a regular expression and a few steps.  Here are all the steps in one keybinding (put in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+b",     // whatever you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
      "commands": [
        {
                     // opens and populates a Find widget
                     // puts a cursor inside every properties[0] object
          "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
          "args": {
            "searchString": "(?<=\"properties\": \\[\\n\\s*\\{)",
            "isRegex": true
          }
        },
        "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "editor.action.selectHighlights",    // select all the find matches (just a cursor so far)
        "editor.action.selectToBracket",
        "cursorRightSelect",                // select the closing bracket too
        // "editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
      ]
  },
  // "when": ""   // in a json file
}
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do once the object is selected. so perhaps this could be extended to do whatever you want to do with it.

Demo:

[image: select object in json with runCommands]

Comment: So this is a valid solution for my use case but not for the generic question, as it also relies on the fact that there is a common pattern you can match in order to find the location for the periodic cursors. In that case I would prefer the solution I already posted as it makes use of the common pattern in a simpler way imho (not having to create a custom keybind but simply using the existing `Ctrl+Shift+L` one).